# Android mask finger paint with other irregurlar shaped images

Tags: android, titanium

I am trying to paint on irregurlar shapes for example its shows completely transparent view to user but he can draw only on the some areas of the view(like an animal shape) this all is done because an animal organ shape will be in the back to the paint view.

[image: image in the back layer in z-axis]

front layer will be transparent view which i will use for painting.

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    boolean containsBG = props.containsKeyAndNotNull(
                                             TiC.PROPERTY_BACKGROUND_COLOR);
    canvas.drawColor(containsBG ?
                    TiConvert.toColor(props, TiC.PROPERTY_BACKGROUND_COLOR) :
                    TiConvert.toColor("transparent"));
    canvas.drawBitmap(tiBitmap, 0, 0, tiBitmapPaint);

    for (int i = 0; i < maxTouchPoints; i++) {
        if (tiPaths[i] != null) {
            canvas.drawPath(tiPaths[i], tiPaint);
        }
    }
}

private void touch_start(int id, float x, float y) {
    tiPaths[id] = new Path();
    tiPaths[id].moveTo(x, y);
    tiX[id] = x;
    tiY[id] = y;
}

private void touch_move(int id, float x, float y) {
    if (tiPaths[id] == null) {
        tiPaths[id] = new Path();
        tiPaths[id].moveTo(tiX[id], tiY[id]);
    }
    tiPaths[id].quadTo(tiX[id], tiY[id], (x + tiX[id]) / 2, (y + tiY[id]) / 2);
    tiX[id] = x;
    tiY[id] = y;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent mainEvent) {
    for (int i = 0; i < mainEvent.getPointerCount(); i++) {
        int id = mainEvent.getPointerId(i);
        float x = mainEvent.getX(i);
        float y = mainEvent.getY(i);
        int action = mainEvent.getAction();
        if (action > 6) {
            action = (action % 256) - 5;
        }
        switch (action) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                finalizePath(id);
                touch_start(id, x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                touch_move(id, x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                finalizePath(id);
                invalidate();
                break;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

public void finalizePath(int id) {
    if (tiPaths[id] != null) {
        tiCanvas.drawPath(tiPaths[id], tiPaint);
        tiPaths[id].reset();
        tiPaths[id] = null;
    }
}

public void finalizePaths() {
    for (int i = 0; i < maxTouchPoints; i++) {
        if (tiPaths[i] != null) {
            tiCanvas.drawPath(tiPaths[i], tiPaint);
            tiPaths[i].reset();
            tiPaths[i] = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Can anybody help in achieving this .thanks in advance

Comment: Can you elaborate your question more ?

Comment: hi GrlsHu i had added images for clear understanding.i want to make use of the painted transparent layer further for some image processing.so i am using two layer.

Comment: how to do this ,please give me advice i have same issue finger paint only image not outside area please....

Answer (score 0):

If you have the mask and it won't change while using your app, maybe you could try this:

1. Set the shape only 2 colors: black and white (like an alpha
   channel). You don't need to show the black and white picture to the
   user. On your human picture on this post, just fill the inside of
   the contour with black, and reference accordingly on your code.
2. Use bitmap.getpixel at every point you want to draw on the picture,
   if it is black you let the paint apply on your function, if it is
   white, you dismiss the function. Usually black is 100%
   transparent, but as your pictures are already with the border white,
   you can do otherwise.